# jSignature - Increase height of signature acceptance area

Tags: html, css, mobile

Using jSignature on a mobile device - all works.

The problem that I am having is that on a phone (like my Galaxy S4) i want to increase the height of the signature drawing area to make it easier to sign. I have passing height & width as well as passing a CSS class ...

```
$('#signature').jSignature({'cssclass': 'signatureWrapper'}).focus();
```

While it appears to increase the size of the surrounding box, it doesn't appear to increase the height of the signature area.

Thanks for any suggestions or guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to target `canvas.jSignature` with your CSS.

CSS File

```
canvas.jSignature { height: 500px; }
```

It looks like you'll also need to change the `height=""` attribute on the `<canvas>` element as well.

I did this on the demo page for jSignature ( http://willowsystems.github.io/jSignature/#/demo/ ) with the Chrome inspector and it worked fine.

Comment: Chris... thanks. Your suggestion resolved most of my issues and pointed me in the right direction.